# mysqladmin says no table in database but list them with 'show tables'

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have phpmyadmin on a webserver connected to several remote mysql (5.5), all is fine like this since years.

Today, for a specific database it says that there is no table in it but a sql query (in the sql tab of this database) 'show tables' is listing tables, and select is listing records.

How could this be possible ?

Edit: I see it's seems incredible, here are screenshots (same user both, just another tab on same db, same server)

The structure tab :

[image: structure tab]

And the sql tab :

[image: sql tab]

Comment: Maybe a temporary table? or user restrictions issues

Comment: Show screenshot of table list and your select query

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a view with a definer who doesn't exists anymore in this database !

After droping the view (and re-create et with a known definer), all is working fine, but it smells like a real bug in phpmyadmin (I haven't the last version installed so I cant't test if it still exists to make a bug report).

It was with a phpmyadmin version 3.4.11

Comment: I tried and wasn't able to reproduce this problem; which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: phpMyAdmin 3 is rather old and not supported anymore; since I'm not able to reproduce this on a more recent version I suspect it's been fixed in the meantime. Glad you were able to work around and resolve the issue anyway.